# Hitchin' a ride

Tags: discussion, answers, spam, late-answers

#### Some background

About 6 months ago an idea emerged in the VBA Code Review chatroom, and together with a fellow VBA reviewer and CR addict, I started working on what became [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/rubberduck), an open-source project that has seen quite a lot of its source code posted and peer reviewed on Code Review.

I did what I think anyone would do with such a project: I started tweeting and blogging about it, and at one point I started googling to see if my stuff was coming up in search results.

- "VBA unit testing" pointed me straight to *[How to unit test Excel VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4547487/1188513)*, where I saw other answers pointing to other tools - [so I added my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798705/1188513).
- "VBA refactoring" took me to *[vba code refactoring - are there any tools to assist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12725195/1188513)*, where the then-most-upvoted answer confirmed how much of a gap my project was filling up - [so I added my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29991570/1188513). I even earned a little bounty for it... but then the question was closed, rightfully, as off-topic.
- "VBA find dead code" lead me to *[Excel forms: identify unused code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7445723/1188513)*, an old answered question, but seeing another answer that pointed to MZ-Tools, [I added my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29689574/1188513).

From my point of view, these answers *directly answer the question that was asked*. If I see a question that Rubberduck can help with, [I take the opportunity to drop a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29482277/1188513).

Other times, it's comments... either as [would-be answer on an off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755286/vba-code-analysis-tools#comment45793900_17755286), as [advice to a beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292171/how-to-create-a-counter-inside-an-event/29292225#comment46781489_29292225), or just as a [comment on someone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036624/vba-expected-for-a-sub/29036793#comment46314761_29036793).

---

#### My problem with it

Just to clarify: I don't actively hunt down [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) questions to sprinkle links on - most of the time I'll post an answer and/or comment and walk away without dropping an unsolicited link. But when I feel that the OP (or posterity) could benefit from seeing what Rubberduck does, i.e. when it's relevant, I can drop a link.

And I feel dirty about it. I recently brought it up in a [comment on my GitHub repository](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/issues/427#issuecomment-98181136) ("RD does not show up easily in search engines #427"):

> *[...] I agree, leveraging Stack Overflow's awesomeness is ...easy. But I feel like a dirty spammer every time I do that.. not to mention that SO questions asking for tools, books or libraries.. are off-topic. These answers are useful for Rubberduck, but they don't make me a very good SO citizen [...]*

I *know* I'm walking along a very thin line here, between *useful for SO* and *useful for RD*. Have I crossed that line (would I know if any of my comments or answers got flagged as spam?)? The last thing I want is to get myself in trouble - are these contributions harmful in any way? Should I remove these answers and comments, or do they provide enough value to stay?

---

## TL;DR

Anyone googling for any of the core features of my VBE add-in will find the above Stack Overflow questions in the top 3 search results, and the answers I've posted there. While I don't feel it's appropriate to be *hitchin' a ride* on the back of SO's search result rankings like this, I also feel that these answers/links *are* very useful to the people that find them, ... but I'm biased, so I'd rather ask here and get the community's point of view.

I need to stop linking to my project, don't I?

---

The reason for this post is the closure of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12725195/1188513), which I would have voted to close under normal circumstances, ...but decided to answer instead: this project is changing my voting, commenting and answering behavior on the site, and it feels wrong.

Comment: This is an interesting conflict of possible bias vs. answering questions with something useful, IMO. I've followed on RD recommendations, and IMHO, I don't think you're overstepping. Community may disagree, and that's also fine.

Comment: I'm not active in the tag so I can't say either way, but I'm very pleased you're proactively bringing this up for discussion on meta.

Comment: If the questions explicitly ask for tools, close them for that reason. The questions you linked are pretty darn old, and don't have a lot of votes for their age. Did they really benefit from having a new answer added?

Comment: Is nobody else spotting the irony here? A meta post about the project for yet another way of discovering it. Genius!

Comment: Jokes aside, this is a valid question

Comment: @Cerbrus according to the very high-level traffic stats I have for my project's website, SO accounts for a consistent 12% of referrals; combined Stack Exchange (SO+CR+chat) accounts for 50-70% of the last 2 months' traffic.

Comment: 50-70% of how many?

Comment: Not a lot. 3-4K

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If it feels wrong, **don't do it**.

Of course, your work might be fantastic - it might actually be a very good idea to link it in your answers. I wouldn't blame you, as long as you don't regard your library as more than it is, and your answers contain substance as well.

But if it changes your way of doing, if you start to accept low-quality questions because you could push your work, and moreover if it feels wrong, **stop**. Being on Stack Overflow shouldn't feel wrong. It should feel good. It should be a bliss - a professional place where enthusiasts can share knowledge.

If you must sacrifice this feeling for a project, then you need to put boundaries between it and this place - because feeling bad is doubleplusungood.

Comment: This is a good answer. My 'razor' for such things (well, actually most things) "When in doubt, don't."

Comment: For me personally, when I see a question asking for recommendations / tools / advice, I vote to close, but I **do** post a comment to his question with some helpful links, because I *still* want to help this person out, and I don't know any other good site where he *can* ask for recommendations / tools / advice. To me this seems right as I can still help the person, while showing him that questions like that are not for SO.

Answer (score 24):

I can't tell you how subsequent activity would be received. I *can* say that the community is known to afford a certain amount of latitude to those that are great contributors in many areas, and where the *perceived intent* of the person posting is apparently benign. As long as your answers are self-contained and don't present quality issues - the community might be tolerant to an extent that you didn't expect.

***They might also not be***, and that's the thing - I can't guarantee how any 10 users working through review or a moderator queue are going to react.

I'd say what you have done thus far isn't bad, you're being completely open about it and your intent is fine - but don't risk it. That said, don't put unnecessary constraints on yourself since you have posted some very helpful answers.

If you find a question where Rubberduck makes a *great* premise for the answer, I don't see the harm - you're doing it *right* by clearly identifying it as something you're affiliated with and giving complete use instructions tailored to the question. But, I wouldn't continue *seeking* places to put it.

tl;dr:

What you've done so far is okay, you've raised the quality of the site a tiny bit, and you've apparently helped people. In the spirit of the subject, I'm going to come out and say ...

#### No harm, no fowl.

... and then get my coat.