# Are affiliate links allowed in answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, hyperlinks

I have searched meta Stack Overflow and have found answers that say something along the lines of "spammy posts with affiliate links will be marked as spam".

However, If I was to post a **detailed, helpful answer to a question**, with a supplemental link to an app from the app store (not necessarily my app), would I be allowed to add my affiliate ID to the end of that link or would that be considered spam?

This question is different from [Hitchin' a Ride](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293459/hitchin-a-ride) because it is about adding affiliate links to *sites that the answerer does not own* such as itunes.apple.com and not about linking to your own product or service.

Comment: your answer needs to stand on its own, WITHOUT the link. Think of it this way : "If the link becomes dead, is my answer still an answer?" If it doesn't.... then it's a bad, spammy answer. If it stands on its own, it's ok. For instance "here is how you foo the bar [full, detailed explanation]. For more info, or for an app that does that, look at [my blog, my app, my website]". But the answer has to be good. If you just say "to foo the bar, use my app"... then no

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2716/179419 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26964/179419

Comment: @Ben i already saw those. thats where i got this question from. if was wondering if an affiliate link in a non-spammy answer is acceptable.

Comment: I think [this answer on a similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293459/hitchin-a-ride/293477#293477) is worth reading

Comment: _"Personally, I would flag any affiliate links as spam."_ is fairly definite @Developer_ACE.

Comment: That is the opinion of one person @ben. I wrote this question because I wanted to see what the rest of the stack overflow community thinks about this.

Comment: @Developer_ACE to give credit where credit is due.... this is the opinion of the CREATOR of the site, so it might be a bit "stronger"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That would be considered spam. Your affiliate ID does nothing to enhance an answer. It serves only to provide you with income. You're not the one incurring a cost by hosting content on Stack Overflow, so you're not the one who deserves to be paid. We're all volunteering our time and knowledge here for free. Allowing affiliate links would give the wrong kind of encouragement for people to post here.

Comment: So if I put my time and effort into crafting quality answers for other users of this site, then I cant be allowed to make a few cents for my time? Also, people could use this post so that they don't get the wrong idea about using affiliate links...

Comment: @Developer_ACE If you want to make money for posting things on the Internet, start your own site. This one is for volunteers.

Comment: This isn't about ME making money. I posted  this question because I wanted to clarify information that was left out of other, similar posts.

Comment: You are however free to put whatever you want in your profile, as long as it isn't offensive.

Comment: @Developer_ACE *"So if I put my time and effort into crafting quality answers for other users of this site, then I cant be allowed to make a few cents for my time?"* It's fine to ask a hypothetical question, but how is that not about you making money?

Comment: @Developer_ACE Wait. so, you're purpose of posting an affialiate link was clarification? why does it need to be linked to your affiliate id if it's purpose is just to clarify?

Comment: @KevinB the purpose of posting this question was to clarify if affiliate links would be allowed if the answer was useful, detailed and could stand alone without the link. in other words, if the link is supplementary to the answer.

Comment: @Developer_ACE This might be an interesting read for you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links SE already auto inserts their own affiliate links for amanzon.

Comment: FWIW, i wouldn't flag the post as spam if the link truly was complementary and the post didn't look spammy. Though, i would first look through your other posts to make sure you aren't' just taking every chance you can to spread said link. I try to always assume good intentions until proven otherwise.

Comment: @KevinB thats what I would do too!